# How to Enable and Disable Image button on Each List Item Click for Lazy Adapter

Tags: android, listview, lazy-loading

Hey Got problem while selecting item in a `ListView`, on each list item `onClick()` i'm trying to enable `button`. `Button` I want to make choice mode single, even though implementing choice mode single in `xml`. Its allowing me multiple selection of my `ImageButton`. What i want to achieve over here is, only user can select one `ListView` item at a time, but over here `ImageButton` is staying clicked for multi selection of `ListView`.
Can anyone help me on this issue please

```
public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

private Activity activity;
private String[] data;
private String[] imageNames;
private String[] creatives;
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
public ImageLoader imageLoader; 
public String assetId;
public LinearLayout creativeSaveChanges,cancelCreative;

public LazyAdapter(Activity a, String[] imageurl,String[] names,String[] creativeId) {
    activity = a;
    data=imageurl;
    imageNames = names;
    creatives = creativeId;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
}

public int getCount() {
    return data.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.boards_creative_custom_listview, null);

    cancelCreative = (LinearLayout)vi. findViewById(R.id.cancelCreative);
    creativeSaveChanges = (LinearLayout)vi. findViewById(R.id.creativeSaveChanges);


    TextView text=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.specialTxtFridaySpecialTroopsList);;
    ImageView image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.imageboardsCreativeList);
    final ImageButton selectbutton = (ImageButton) vi.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonRefreshListCreative);
    text.setText(imageNames[position]);
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(data[position], image);

     vi.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            selectbutton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rightblue);
             assetId = creatives[position];
            Log.e("creatives", assetId);

              for (int i = 0; i <creatives.length; i++) {
               if(i == position){
                    Log.e("creatives.length", i+" ,"+position+"");
               }else if(i != position){
                    selectbutton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    Log.e("creatives.length", i+" and "+position+"");
               }
            }
        }
    });

    return vi;
}


}
```

Comment: image.setenable(false) or image.setenable(true)

Comment: Nope Doesnt work in that way, cause we trying each list item click. Imagine ive clicked on list item 1 button should be enable, on clicking list item 2 item 1 button should disabled and enabled in item 2.

Comment: using value true or false when u click the list view itemclick  update your listview using notifidatachange may be its logic

Comment: Well its Lazy adapter mate, cant invoke itemclick. Only thing we can implement in vi.onclicklistener.

Comment: Pass One More argumanet to Lazy adapter like true or false array and update its value when u click on listview and reload  listview